# Question about canonical quantization of the open string ghost system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, commutator, quantization, ghosts

In section 3.1.3 of Green, Schwarz and Witten book on superstrings, it is stated that
the canonical anti commutation relations for the fermionic ghosts are

$$ \{ b_{++}(\sigma, \tau), c^+(\sigma', \tau)\} = 2\pi \delta (\sigma -\sigma')\\
 \{ b_{--}(\sigma, \tau), c^-(\sigma', \tau)\} = 2\pi \delta (\sigma -\sigma') \label{11}$$

And with the open string mode expansions of these ghosts as

$$c^+ = \sum c_n e^{-in(\tau + \sigma)}\\
c^- = \sum c_n e^{-in(\tau - \sigma)} \\
b_{++} = \sum b_n e^{-in (\tau + \sigma)} \\
b_{--} = \sum b_n e^{-in (\tau - \sigma)} $$

Now, from the canonical anti commutation relations at $\tau=0$, I am trying to obtain the anti commutation relations for the modes. I start with

$$\{ b_{++}(\sigma, 0), c^+(\sigma', 0)\} = \sum_{mn} e^{-im \sigma} e^{-in \sigma'} \{b_m, c_n\} $$

Using $\{b_m , c_n\} = \delta_{m+n}$, we get

$$\{ b_{++}(\sigma, 0), c^+(\sigma', 0)\} = \sum_m e^{-im (\sigma - \sigma')} \\
\hspace{3.7cm}\stackrel{?}{=} 2\pi \delta(\sigma - \sigma').$$

And I get the same expression for $\{ b_{--}(\sigma, \tau), c^-(\sigma', \tau)\}$.

Question: How do I prove the last equality knowing that sigma runs from $0$ to $\pi$ ?

PS: I want to evaluate these anti commutation relations without using the doubling trick.